# Unix command via Ruby script not effective

Tags: ruby, macos, shell

I like my terminal output to be coloured.
I don't like to deal with bash profiles.

So I used to simply execute these 2 commands in the terminal (macOS):

```
export CLICOLOR=1
export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced
```

It does the job.
Of course it quickly became tiring to write them every-time I wanted my shell to be coloured.

So I thought: let's automate these actions with a Ruby script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

puts "\n======== COLOR ME =======\n"

puts %x{export CLICOLOR=1}
puts %x{export LSCOLORS=GxFxCxDxBxegedabagaced}
puts "You are now colored\n"
puts ""
```

Therefore, being in the right directory, my intention was to simply execute this simple named script instead:

```
ruby colorme.rb
```

Here is the problem:
It used to work when I created it.
Now we are just a few days later and it does not work anymore. I have no idea why...
I didn't update anything, didn't move any files (that's what I think at least)...

Any thoughts ?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Sorry but you can't define environment variables for the calling shell with Ruby. Just add these exports to your `~/.bash_profile` or whatever

Comment: @Fravadona Thank you. I better understand why my script is not effective now. Unfortunately, using the bash_profile file is not a solution for me. My job requires to work on many different computers (different OS versions) all the time. Running a simple script sounded more attractive to me (from a workflow perspective) than modifying many different bash profiles everyday on different systems, different environments. Writing a script to modify bash profiles or to replace bash profile files also sound risky, not workable, not maintainable to me. Anyway, thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

With `%x{...}`, a subshell is launched (i.e. `/bin/sh`), and the contents are executed. The output is returned.

Since this is run in a subshell, which exits, the changes will not affect the running ruby interpreter, nor the parent shell of ruby.

This is a case where you have to "deal with bash profiles".

Comment: Thank you. I better understand why my script is not effective now. Unfortunately, using the bash_profile file is not a solution for me. My job requires to work on many different computers (different OS versions) all the time. Running a simple script sounded more attractive to me (from a workflow perspective) than modifying many different bash profiles everyday on different systems, different environments. Writing a script to modify bash profiles or to replace bash profile files also sound risky, not workable, not maintainable to me. Anyway, thank you for the clarification.

Comment: I have all my dot-files and configs stored in git. When I go to a new machine, I can basically just git clone and I have my preferred environment ready to go.

Comment: Cheers, I'll look into it. I just need it to be nondestructive at all (like I never went there) and fast enough (faster than simply typing the 2 export commands). Nevertheless, the git clone sounds like a nice method when I deal with brand new computers that do not belong to anyone yet.

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that the `export` statement does not write anything to stdout and hence you don't have anything `puts` can show you, your `%x` commands spawn a child process, and **inside this process** you set the environment variables. Of course you can't see them afterwards. For instance, if you would do a

```
puts %{export foo=bar; printenv foo}
```

(assuming you have `printenv` in your PATH), you would see the value printed, although this could be achieved simpler by

```
system "export foo=bar; printenv foo".
```

If you want to set environment variables in your current process, you have to use the `ENV` hash:

```
ENV['foo']='bar'
system("printenv foo") # prints bar
```

This is independent of the shell you are running in your subprocess.